# Plotting a categorical variable against another categorical variable

Tags: r, plot

I am comparing different clustering methods and I would like to see if two different methods (or sets of parameters) are defining similar clusters or not. My clusters are defined as categorical factors (categorical variables) in a data frame.

If I use `plot()` with *x* being a categorical variable and *y* being a continuous variable I get a *box plot*. If I do the same but *y* being another categorical variable I get some weird *bar plot* (figure below). How do you interpret this king of plot?

[image: plot you get when plotting a categorical variable against another categorical variable]

In this plot,*x* (df$category1) has 13 levels:

`[1] "A"        "B"        "C"        "D"        "cluster1" "cluster5"
 [7] "cluster2" "cluster8" "cluster0" "cluster6" "cluster4" "cluster3"
[13] "cluster7"`

and *y* (df$category2) has only 12 levels :

`[1] "A"        "B"        "C"        "D"        "cluster5" "cluster0"
 [7] "cluster4" "cluster2" "cluster3" "cluster6" "cluster1" "cluster7"`

A, B, C, and  D are the same between the two columns, the rest if clusters are not necessarily the same as are the result of different clustering runs.

**Edit** : the code used was `plot(df$category1, df$category2)`

Comment: What code did you use to create this?

Comment: `plot(df$category1, df$category2)`

Comment: Also describe what the story is you want the plot to tell.

Comment: @pedrosaurio:  That still doesn't make your problem reproducible.  You need to provide sample data.  For two categorical variables, you get a spineplot, though the default spineplot doesn't look like your plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `x` and `y` are both factors, `plot` calls `spineplot`.  Example from that function's help page:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2),
    labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),
    levels = c(1, 2, 3),
    labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))

spineplot(improved, treatment)
```

Though this looks a little different to the plot you have.

Comment: `spineplot` that is what I wanted to know. I guess they don't look as they should because levels A, B, C, and D are the same in both factors.

Comment: Thanks. This is totally Google-proof! There is no way you would know a plot of x,y both being categorical variables is rendered in R as a *spineplot*. (ok unless you reverse-searched every page of every basic plot function)

Answer (score 3):

Not what you asked, but try mosaicplot(). It'll produce a graphic suitable for two categorical variables.